# Scan for hosts in a LAN from outside of the LAN given it's public IP ( i.e IP of the router )

Tags: networking, router, lan, nat, hosts

Is there any possible way to **scan** for **hosts** behind a **router** by knowing the router's **IP address** and the **network address** of the LAN ?

I don't mean port scanning of hosts behind a router 
where NAT's and port-forwarding things kick's in,

I just mean which hosts are available in LAN behind a router.

Thank's.

**PS**: I tried Reverse-DNS querying a router (not my router) for all possible IP addresses of the LAN (since I know it's network address).although it works but it always shows hostnames for IP's no matter if the host is up or not.

Comment: In a correctly configured gateway scenario, what you ask for is impossible on purpose. you would probably need to compromise the router, or deploy a RAS kit on a host within the LAN. Absent one of these methods, you have little hope of enumerating the hosts on the LAN directly.

Comment: when I reverse DNS query a private IP address using the gateway IP as DNS server, it replies me back with hostname if that IP is up in the LAN. is this something A gateway shouldn't do?

Comment: I would agrue that your routers DNS server is mis-configured if it is resolving queries for clients outside the LAN, yes. I would certainly never allow people outside my lan to access my DNS server, but stateful firewalling with UDP is difficult, so you should probably lock down your firewall to allow udp\53 traffic only from known DNS servers you forward to from the inside, so that their responses come in, but no one can see your DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. And its a fundamental side effect of how NAT and IP masquerading works.

Unless you explicitly tell your router (which in the case of a consumer unit, is really a firewall handling NAT and masquerading as well as a switch and a router) to divert traffic at a certain port to a certain client. So unless you're behind the lan, its going to be pretty tricky finding out what's behind it unless you're sniffing all the traffic out of the router and using information from there, it ought to be impossible to tell how many, or what PCs there are.

While there's ways around this, all of them involve being *inside* the network,

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so without using nefarious methods, I would also question the reasons for wanting to do so...

(this assumes you have no access to the LAN)